# Why doesn't this type-checking work in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, typing

From the following function where I'm using typing:

```
@router.get("", response_model=List[schemas.PostResponse])
def get_posts(db: Session = Depends(get_db), user_id: int = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
    posts = db.query(models.Post).all()[:2]
    return posts
```

If I change the type of the function arguments to blantantly incorrect types, such as:

```
@router.get("", response_model=List[schemas.PostResponse])
def get_posts(db: set = Depends(get_db), user_id: tuple = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
    posts = db.query(models.Post).all()[:2]
    return posts
```

It still works just fine. Is that expected behavior, in that the type-checking is more for code-editors than actually enforcing type? Is there any better way to enforce type here -- for example, why might be a better way to write the above where the two parameters must have the specified type?

Comment: Unlike languages like C or C++ Python does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc. see [typing — Support for type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for more details.

Comment: @itprorh66 I see, so in the above, how would you write a 'type-safe' function to accomplish the above? Or would you just not be using python in the first place?

Comment: If you mean "enforce at run time", you can always write as much code as you want to check your arguments and raise exceptions if you don't like them. Just have to ask yourself why, what you are accomplishing by checking them at runtime vs allowing them in. Sometimes it might be useful, sometimes not. The best ways to check things at run time will depend on what you're checking and why.

Comment: If you mean "enforce before it's run", then run a linter on the code before you run it. If your linter is not catching this, you might want to ask a more specific question about that. If you mean "enforce that others run a linter", I think you're right that Python just doesn't have that capability.